# How to check the corruption of a file?

Tags: c++, c, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm developping a blackberry 10 mobile application using the momentics IDE (native sdk).

In my code, I want to add a function that should check if a file is corrupted or not .

How should I do proceed ?

Comment: What file? what corruption? why would it be corrupted?

Comment: Depends on the file. Suppose you download a text file and then abort half way through. Theoretically this is a "corrupted" text file but how would you know just by looking at the file?

Comment: I'm loading files (images) from server and saving them localy, but sometimes some of these files came corrupted. So, all I want is to add some code that can check if the selected file is corrputed or not to see if the app. should replace it with the default file (image) or not.

Comment: The only way is to play hard - that's how I found out that my ".emacs" had been taking bribes from the kernel. They caved once I threatened them with a Windows ME installation. HTH, YMMV. ;-)

Comment: @user2072762 Is there any way you can add a checksum file server-side?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not !

Comment: @user2072762 Did you try to create a QPixmap object of the questionable file and see if it succeeds? e.g. `QPixmap qpixmap ("/path/to/suspicious_file.jpg");`

Comment: Most probably you are handling communication incorrectly possibly you don't handle any errors.

Comment: Actualy, I did !! For a reason that I didin't find, some of the content images contain html code.

Comment: Don't try to work around the bug, but find it!

Answer (score 2):

Two methods I can think of: -

1) If you're writing out the file, ensure you have a specific set of bytes that you write out at the end. When reading the file in, move to the end of the file and check if those bytes are present. If not, the file didn't finish writing and can be considered corrupt. Alternatively to this is to write out the size of bytes to the beginning of the file and check to see if the rest of the file size is equal to that number when it is read back in.

2) If you're checking a file that doesn't change, store a hash of the contents of the file and at run-time, generate the hash and compare it to the one you've stored. If they differ, the file has been modified and you can consider it corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by corrupted?

If you want to see if the file is what you expect or not, you can calculate a hash of the file, like `SHA-256` or whatever hashing algorithm you like, store the hash values, and then in your application simply calculate the hash values of the files, compare to what you expect, and if they're the same, there is most probably no corruption.

You might want to have a look [here](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function).